# Client Side JMS Configuration - JMS Cluster - Connets to only one server

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, cluster-computing, session-cookies

So i wrote a program to connect to a Clustered WebLogic server behind a VIP with 4 servers and 4 queues that are all connected( i think they call them distributed...) When i run the program from my local machine and just get JMS Connections, look for messages and disconnect, it works great. and by that i mean it:

- iteration #1

  - connects to server 1.
  - look for a message
  - disconnects
- iteration #2

  - connects to server 2.
  - look for a message
  - disconnects

and so on.

When i run it on the server though, the application picks a server and stick to it. It will never pick a new server, so the queues on the other servers don't ever get worked. like with a "sticky session" setup...  My OS is Win7, and the Server os is Win2008r2 JDK is identical for both machines..  How is this configured client side?  The server implementation uses "Apache Procrun" to run it as a service. but i haven't seen too many issues with that part...

is there a session cookie getting written out somewhere?

any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling 'Server Affinity' on the JMS Connection factory.  If you are using the Default Connection Factory, define your own an disable Server Affinity.

**EDIT:**
Server Affinity is a Server-side setting, but it controls how messages are routed to consumers after a WebLogic JMS Server receives the message.  The other option is to use round-robin DNS and send to only one hostname that resolves to a different IP(Managed Server) such that each connection goes to a different server.

I'm pretty sure this is the setting you're looking for :)

Comment: Thanks! i'll look around.

I was thinking this would be a client setting instead of a server setting.  The way its currently handling "server affinity" seems to be related to the client running the code, not the server...